# Skin modifiers automated armature loses influence over mesh after applying modifier. What can I do?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, armature, texture-painting

( Beginner question )

I first created character using skin modifier. Next I made armature through skin modifier. Next I animated character and everything in posing worked, I saved animation data.

Next I applied skin modifier ( I had to do it in order to texture paint character later ). Armature stayed but it lost influence over mesh completely, my animations stopped working ( Only armature was animated, mesh stayed in place ).

How can I fix this ? Is there an easy way to regain armature influence with the same weights ? Or should I work around this problem by somehow not applying modifier in the end ?

The only thing I care about is to both be able to use skin modifiers simple automated armature, as well as be able to texture paint my character

Comment: Have you tried to parent (Ctrl+P, With Automatic Weights) the armature and the mesh?

Comment: Chances are you applied the armature modifier by mistake. Recreate one, and set it to “bone envelopes”

Comment: Thank You both just as much, both sollutions work ! :*